# How can I extend a div to bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

How can I extend a div to the bottom of the page? Let's say I have a div that starts at the top, and has a background image I want repeated to the bottom of the page. How would I go about doing this?

Live example found here: http://mibsolutionsllc.com/ecgridos/about/ with the #content div.

Answer (score 4):

Switch it around, have the background for your content as the body tags back ground then over lay the header over the top of it via a div or other element :)

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) does something similar, they've got a solution that seems to work on a whole range of different (including very old) browsers. If you don't need the footer you can always still use their solution and set the footer height to 0px.